# Close button on top-right clipped

Tags: html, css

I have a div `#main` that contains an image of variable or bigger size. I want to put a close button on its top right that stretches out of the div a bit using negative margins.
I am using `overflow:hidden` on my `#main` div to prevent the main image from stretching out of the div. But that is also clipping my close button.

I have the following html :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="close">x</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS :

```
#container{
    background:#555;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#close{
    background:#069;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:-10px -10px 0 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zFjdf/ and you can see that the close is clipped.

I want to have the close button show completely without letting the `#main`'s image stretch out of it.

Comment: What about putting the `#close` inside the `#container` instead of the clipped `#main`?

Comment: Yes .. i wasn't thinking outside the (#main) box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the content of `#main` in another `div` that has `overflow` set to `hidden`, something along tis lines:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="close">x</div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and remove the `overflow` property form `#main`.

#### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFjdf/4/)

Additionally, for the `#close` box you could use `padding` instead of `width`/`heignt` to have the X centered. And you should consider using `class` instead of `id` to apply style, especially f you are planning on having multiple occurrences of the `main` element on the same page .